# Spider not scraping a list or urls

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider that gets the URLs to scrape from a list. My problem is that, when I run the spider, no data is being scraped and, what is weird to me and I can't seem to be able to solve is that the spider is indeed entering each site, but not data comes back out.

My spider looks like this

```
import scrapy
import re
import pandas
import json
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from genericScraper.items import ClothesItem
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

class ClothesSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "clothes_spider"

    #Dominio permitido
    allowed_domain = ['www.amazon.com']

    colnames = ['nombre', 'url']

    data = pandas.read_csv('URLClothesData.csv', names = colnames)

    name_list = data.nombre.tolist()

    URL_list = data.url.tolist()

    #Sacamos los primeros de ambas, que seria el indice
    name_list.pop(0)
    URL_list.pop(0)

    start_urls = URL_list

    custom_settings = {

        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI' : 'ClothesData.csv'

    }

    def parse_item(self,response):

        cothesAmz_item = ClothesItem()
        cothesAmz_item['nombreProducto'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[contains(@id, "productTitle")]/text())').extract()

        yield cothesAmz_item
```

What I see in my console is this

[ConsoleLightshotPicture](http://prntscr.com/m3owd0)

Comment: By default `scrapy` calls the spider's `.parse()` method for each url in `start_urls`... it looks like you want to either be calling `parse_item` at some point in that chain, or that `parse_item` should be renamed to `parse`...

Comment: Well that was a dumb error, thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd personally also not put the loading code into the class definition itself... rather put it in a `start_requests()` method and do it there... You might also want to look at [spider arguments](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments) so you can pass the CSV to be used using that instead of hard coding it in the spider... that way it may make your spider more generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when spider crawl through start_urls then its `default callback` function is:

```
def parse(self, response):
    pass    #Your logic goes here,
```

You can try changing your function `parse_item` to `parse`.